I have created a chart in Excel but the percentage bar length is not increasing
I have created a chart in Excel but the percentage bar length is not increasing. All data is fine in chart, only the bars length is the issue.



A percentage in Excel is represented as a portion of 1.  So 73% is 0.78. When shown next to a value of 58,206.83 you won't be able to see it change the differences are so large.

is there any way where i can show the percentage bars in comparison to the budget provided

Percent values should be on a secondary axis.

Either a secondary axis as @MGonet suggests or calculate the value - 73% of 6394.007 is 5370.966 so use that as the percentage bar and attach the percent label to it.

There are multiple approaches to achieve your result, depending on what exact visualisation you want to achieve in the end. In your case it doesn't work, because your numbers are in the thousands, while the percentages are interpreted as fractions, i.e., 73% is interpreted as 0.73. For this reason, you don't see it in the chart, despite in theory being there.
With your current data, the easiest option is to put the percentages on the secondary axis. Highlight your data > Insert > Charts > All Charts > Combo. Here put the chart type of the "Monthly budget" to e.g., a line with markers and the others as a clustered column and tick the box for the secondary axis. This will give you the following chart, where you can of course tweak the chart type etc.

An easy approach to have all columns, but still percentage labels could look as follows. First, compute the monetary value for all your percentages. Assuming your data is stored in the range A1:E8, you put in cell F2 the following formula =$B2*C2 and copy it in the range F2:H8.



Expenses
Monthly budget
January
February
March
January
February
March




Retail
57,632
124%
122%
122%
71463.06
70310.43
70310.43


Direct Sales
58,207
84%
86%
86%
48893.74
50057.87
50057.87


Telesales
44,017
104%
104%
104%
45777.77
45777.77
45777.77


Airport
6,394
73%
75%
75%
4667.625
4795.505
4795.505


MT
9,059
78%
87%
87%
7065.94
7881.241
7881.241


Express
24,570
90%
92%
92%
22112.57
22603.96
22603.96


Backend
5,889
165%
165%
165%
9716.164
9716.164
9716.164



Now, use expenses, monthly budget and the columns with monetary values > Insert > Charts > All Charts > Column > Clustered Column. Highlight a series in the chart by clicking on one of the bars and then right click > Add data labels > Click on the data labels > right click > Format Data Labels. In the Label Options select Value From Cells and then highlight the corresponding row with percentages and remove the tick from Value (repeat for the other series where you want data labels). Now you can tweak the labels according to your needs in terms of size, color, angle etc. The result could look as follows:

